# Not able to hide Index.php page on URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I run a site using Joomla cms where we disabled `index.php` in URL but it doesn't work now

```
mysite.com/index.php
```

Then we tried with `.htaccess` file with following commands then at the homepage its disabled

```
       # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
```

Works fine on the home page alone

```
mysite.com
```

But when I pass to any page from the home page it throws an error, when I tried with index.php in between then it works,

```
mysite.com/something    #throws error with this URL
mysite.com/index.php/something  # works fine with this URL
```

I need help to permanently disable the `index.php` inside URL even when I try to pass on to any other page from the home page, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable 'Use URL rewriting' at Joomla global configuration > Site > SEO Settings ?

Comment: yeah, it's enabled only

Comment: Maybe this topic can help https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/500-internal-server-error-after-renaming-htaccess-txt-to-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Did you add following lines at the beginning?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# your rules here

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```